# Listview image on columns

Tags: winforms, listview

I have a listview (details view) and I display a column of images and a column of text,
It's possible to display the image in the second column (without OwnerDraw)? I want to put the text in the first because only the first column can be edited by the user (LabelEdit property)

```
ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem("");
lvi.ImageKey = "image";      // column 1
lvi.SubItems.Add("subitem 2"); // column 2
```

Thank You

UPDATE

Native listview supports images in subitems (LVS_EX_SUBITEMIMAGES) since before win 98 but they didn't include it in .NET.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774732(v=vs.85).aspx

A codeproject example 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7630/ListView-with-Image-on-SubItems

Answer (score 1):

No, without `OwnerDraw` it is not possible.

In your case the simplest thing is to manage the editing of other columns instead of manage the `OwnerDraw`. There are some example of how to do it:

[example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/471859/c-how-do-you-edit-items-and-subitems-in-a-listview)
[example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587241/editable-subitems-within-a-listview)
[example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880773/edit-item-or-subitem-values-of-a-selected-listview-item)

ecc...

Comment: I think it's easier painting the image with OwnerDraw than editing subitems :)